# Hide Device ID details in Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, xcode6

This has just appeared in Xcode - Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Any idea how to hide it.

[image]

[image]

Must have have something to do with installing the beta.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Can you post a full picture of that table? (I never seen this on Xcode , using 8.4 right now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happened to me before. Please check if in your device setting for some reason there might be some duplicates. If two devices have the same name and version number, it will show the devices' UDIDs. So just go to **Windows > Devices** in Xcode to delete or rename your devices.

Answer (score 1):

The problem on hand is that you have two different simulator installed. This is why you have two devices of each pair and their **UDID** is attached in the back, in order for you to identify them. In order to solve that, you can just de-install one of the simulator as so:

Go to:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

and delete one of the installed SDKs. You should have two of them. Then also delete one of the corresponding `.dmg`s at:

> ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads

When you uninstall one of them, you'll automatically go back to having one Simulator and thus not seeing the UDID in the back.

Hope that helps,

Julian